# Dockerfile RUN command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to execute the following command in my dockerfile:

```
java -jar kafka-connect-cli-1.0.6-all.jar create cassandra-sink-orders < cassandra-sink-distributed-orders.properties
```

This is what I have tried but it gives me error:

**Cannot execute cassandra-sink-orders < cassandra-sink-distributed-orders.properties**

```
CMD ["java", "-jar", "kafka-connect-cli-1.0.6-all.jar", "create", "cassandra-sink-orders", "<", "cassandra-sink-distributed-orders.properties"]
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output redirection using `<` is a shell feature. When supplying a JSON list to `CMD`, the command will not be executed by a shell.

To use shell feature, use one of the following forms:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "java -jar kafka-connect-cli-1.0.6-all.jar create cassandra-sink-orders < cassandra-sink-distributed-orders.properties"]
CMD java -jar kafka-connect-cli-1.0.6-all.jar create cassandra-sink-orders < cassandra-sink-distributed-orders.properties
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> The CMD instruction has three forms:
>
> - `CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]` (*exec* form, this is the preferred form)
> - `CMD ["param1","param2"]` (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
> - `CMD command param1 param2` (*shell* form)
>
> [...]
>
> **Note:** Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example, `CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ]` will not do variable substitution on `$HOME`. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example: `CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME" ]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run it in this way :

```
CMD "java -jar kafka-connect-cli-1.0.6-all.jar create cassandra-sink-orders < cassandra-sink-distributed-orders.properties"
```